# For loop for printing unicode characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I did a basic for loop in Python as I wanted to print all possible charactes using unicode notation.

```
for i in range(1000,1100):
    print('\\u'+str(i))
```

and it prints the following

```
...
\u1077
\u1078
\u1079
```

and so on...

I don't understand why loop prints strings like that, but if I executed just:

```
print('\u0227')
```

it would have printed ȧ.

I don't understand the difference between printing as a concatenated string from for loop vs printing it just by calling print and typing a unicode representation. Also a string generated by for loop seems to need one more backslash for escaping.

I called type function and in both cases it says those are strings as they are but just wanted to be sure since of this behaviour.

Comment: use `chr` instead of `str`. `chr(0x227)` -> `'ȧ'`

Comment: To get something like that to work, you'd need to do `print((b'\\u%d' % i).decode('raw_unicode_escape'))`.

Answer (score 3):

So called **string literals** in code are processed before they become strings. A backslash in a string marks that something follows that must be interpreted specially.

- If followed by a second backslash, the final string is rendered to
  just contain one backslash. So **string literal** `'\\u'` becomes
  **string** `\u`
- If followed by a `u` and four hexadecimal digits the whole sequence
  (including the backslash) in the literal become the denoted unicode character in the string: Literal `'\u0227'` becomes string `ȧ`

As Paul Panzer already wrote, `chr()` (for Python 3.x) or `unichr()` (for Python 2.x) take the number of a unicode character and return a string containing only this character.